# ActiveMQ MQTT Producer not publish to openwire Subscriber

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

i'm trying to test the ActiveMQ protocol wrapper.
I have write a MQTT Client with Eclipse Paho 1.0.2
The openwire client is the ActiveMQ Client.
and the Broker is ActiveMQ version 5.14.4.

all Clients working with topics and Subscribers

the Comunication from MQTT client to MQTT Client works perfekt, and the Openwire Client too.

But if i try to send from MQTT to Openwire, the Openwire client is not getting the messages from MQTT client. To Publish from Openwire to MQTT works perfekt.
I have try it with all difeerent qos settings.

my Config from ActiveMQ is the standart Config

```
<transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"  updateClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" updateClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" updateClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" updateClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" updateClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

an the publish code is similar the original paho sample:

```
MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
            sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            System.out.println("Publishing message: "+content);
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
            message.setQos(qos);
            sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
            System.out.println("Message published");
            sampleClient.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            System.exit(0);
```

Any body an idee whats wrong or is this normal?

Comment: Have you looked at the ActiveMQ Web Console to see what Topics the MQTT client and OpenWire client are producing and consuming to?  Often people get the names wrong.

Comment: no its all correct, all the same names, the mqtt subscriber is consuming the messages only the openwire subscriber is not getting the messages.

Comment: ok have found the problem, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723073/how-to-produce-from-mqtt-and-consume-as-mqtt-and-jms-in-activemq?rq=1) has the correct answare. The problem is mqtt is sending bytemessages the openwire(JMS) client was checking of textmessages and has discard the message